# Gantt chart that can add multiple time slots for a activity

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, gantt-chart

I’m in need of a jQuery Gantt chart that can have multiple time slots applied for a particular activity. But unfortunately only I have found ones that support only single timeslot for a particular activity. Would be grateful if anyone can suggest me a one that supports my requirement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure if this meets your criteria, but you might want to check out [jQuery.Gantt](http://taitems.github.io/jQuery.Gantt/).

You can specify any number of values (optionally-labeled date-time ranges) per source item. The chart displays one source item per line, with each line containing all of the ranges for that item. As is shown in the documentation, the source you would pass as an option can be a URL or an array of value objects:

```
// ...
source: [{
    name: "Example",
    desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
    values: [ ... ]
// ...
}]
```

and `values` would look like this:

```
values: [{
    from: '2014/01/23', // date can be a string (YYYY/MM/DD ...),
    to: 1392743873913,  // integer (ms), or Date instance
    desc: "Something",
    label: "Example Value",
    customClass: "ganttRed",
    dataObj: foo.bar[i]
}]
```

Example JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8FnE9/5/